# Эффект разбития

Tags: jquery, javascript

http://www.linkexchanger.su/jquery_effects_core/explode.html

Эффект хороший, но не работает если сам блок транспорент и наложен бэкраудн внутри. Как быть? Возможно использовать такой эффект или делать картинками?

Comment: пример на jsfiddle как именно не работает. по идее background-position должно помочь